# Editing variables with GetComponent C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a conveyor belt to reverse its direction when the player presses a button.

Here's the code for the conveyor belt

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Conveyor : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 1.0f;

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        col.transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

And the code for the button

```
public class PushButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Button;

    private Conveyor conveyor;

    void Awake ()
    {
        conveyor = GetComponent<Conveyor>();
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider entity)
    {
        if (entity.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
            {
                conveyor.speed = conveyor.speed * -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error saying "Object Reference not set to the instance of an object PushButton.OnTriggerStay (Unity Engine.Collider entity) (at Assests/PushButton.cs21)

I'm still not very familiar with using getComponent so I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NOTE "public GameObject Button" variables MUST be lower case, so it would be "button".  Also note, there is a thing in Unity called "Button" so you would probably not use that. Call it something like "topLeftRedButton", for example

Answer (score 0):

GetComponent will need a reference to an initialized object and a component or class that object has assigned. For what you are wanting, you will want to find a game object in the scene. Because you are already specifying that your GameObject has a Conveyor class assigned to it, find your GameObject and then specify the Conveyor component.

```
void Awake ()
 {
 conveyor = GameObject.FindWithTag("Conveyor").GetComponent<Conveyor>();
 }
```

This should do the trick pending you have tagged your Conveyor game object with a 'Conveyor' tag.

However, there is *an even easier way* to quickly "grab" something like this.  Be careful though!

```
void Awake()
 {
 conveyor = Object.FindObjectOfType<Conveyor>();
 // ONLY DO THAT IF THERE IS ONLY >>ONE<< OF THE THING!
 }
```

Here's a little essay on that. http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/46285/view.html

You often do that for example to find "boss" objects .. scene managers and the like.

Don't forget though, you can always just **use a public variable, and drag inteh Inspector - that's always a sound idea for beginners working with Unity.**